# isMultipartContent(request) is not working. I dont know what is happening, it should return true but it is returning false

Tags: java, jsp

I am using this code to upload a file(image) in a web application using jsp. And here in this code isMultipartContent(request) should return true but it returns false. I am not getting what is wrong.

```
<form class="form-contact contact_form" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" name="ff_ctype" id="ctype" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Course Type'" placeholder = 'Course Type'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input  name="cupload" id="cupload" type="file">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mt-3">
                        <button type="submit" name="up_btn" value="submit" class="button button-contactForm btn_1">UPLOAD</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
<%
            String ctype="", cimage="", path="";
            boolean successful=true;
            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);  
            if(isMultipart) {
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                List<FileItem> items = null;
                try {
                    items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                }
                catch (FileUploadException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for(FileItem myitem:items) {
                    if (myitem.isFormField()) {
                        String itemName1 = myitem.getFieldName();
                        String value=myitem.getString();
                        if(itemName1.equals("ff_ctype")) //control's name - textbox name
                        {
                            ctype=value;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        String type=myitem.getContentType();
                        long size=myitem.getSize()/1024; //kbytes
                        if(size==0) {
                            cimage="default.png";
                        }
                        else if((type.equals("image/pjpeg") 
                                || type.equals("image/jpeg")
                                || type.equals("image/png") 
                                || type.equals("image/x-png")
                                || type.equals("image/gif")) 
                                && size<400)
                        {
                            cimage=new java.util.Date().getTime()+myitem.getName();
                            path=config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "uploads\\" + cimage;
                            File savefile=new File(path);
                            myitem.write(savefile);
                        }
                        else {
                            successful=false;
                            out.print("Sorry only pictures of less than 400kb are allowed to upload");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(successful==true) {
                    try {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        Connection MyConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(PATH + PLACE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        try {
                            String q1="insert into coursetypes(ctype, cimage) values(?,?)";
                            PreparedStatement insertvalues=MyConnection.prepareStatement(q1);
                            insertvalues.setString(1, ctype);
                            insertvalues.setString(2, cimage);
                            if(insertvalues.executeUpdate()==1) {
                                out.print("Image Uploaded Successfully");
                            }
                            else {
                                out.print("Error occured");
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            out.print("Error in query due to: " + e.getMessage());
                        } 
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        out.print("Error in connection due to: "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    %>
```

There are no error messages.

This code should upload the file in uploads folder in my project but its very first step is going wrong, i.e., isMultipartContent(request) is returning false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was i used form method='get'. But multipart does not work with get method. Because, to my knowledge, as the image cannot be displayed on addressbar so this does not work. All the code displayed here is perfectly working.

The wrong code was:-

```
<form method="get">
```

The right way is:-

```
<form method="post">
```

After this it was working perfectly fine.